# How can I end a CSS animation early?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I am using CSS animation to make a progress bar.

- When a user clicks a button, a `searching` class is added
- The `searching` class is styled with a CSS animation that takes 100 seconds

[Here's a working JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kmer8s5c/1/)

Since this is a progress bar for searching, sometimes the search will take less than the animation time - at which point I want the animation to end. I've added a timeout to the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kmer8s5c/1/).

However **a timeout to add a class to make the progress-bar 100% width (the final state of the animation) doesn't work**. The browser still displays the progress bar as whatever width the animation uses until the animation is complete.

**How can I end a CSS animation early, using JavaScript?**

Comment: Your animation won't stop until it's finished or until you remove the class .searching. Instead of just adding a .finished class, you should toggle the .searching one first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shift the `completed` class outside of `searching`, so the animation no longer applies, then simply remove the `searching` class:

SCSS:

```
.progress-bar {
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #222;
  .completion {
    width: 0%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: green;
    &.searching {
      animation-duration: 60s;
      animation-name: show-progress;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    &.completed {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
}
```

JS:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  progress.classList.remove('searching')
  progress.classList.add('completed') 
  console.log('Added completed')
}, 1*1000)
```

Here's [an updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/03r6h8wa/).

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `animation-duration` of the progress:

```
  &.completed {
    width: 100%;
    animation-duration: 3s;
  }
```

Here is the working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/kmer8s5c/2/

Comment: I'm going to award it to James as his is just a little simpler, but thanks for the answer, it works perfectly!